# How to use props for method in mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to use props I get through `mapStateToProps` in `mapDispatchToProps`. How can I do that?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      resultItems: res,
      loading: state.loading,
      lastQuery: state.lastQuery,
      selectedCat: state.selectedCat
  }

};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    sendClickedQuery(selectedCat) {

        // Use props as parameters here
        dispatch(mutations.sendQuery(lastQuery, selectedCat));
    }
});

export const ConnectedMain = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

Comment: @BrianThompson That returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mergeProps` which is an optional parameter of connect like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      resultItems: res,
      loading: state.loading,
      lastQuery: state.lastQuery,
      selectedCat: state.selectedCat
  }

};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    sendClickedQuery(selectedCat) {
        dispatch(mutations.sendQuery(lastQuery, selectedCat));
    }
});

const mergeProps = (propsFromState, propsFromDispatch) => (
    {
      ...propsFromState,
      ...propsFromDispatch,
      sendQuery: propsFromDispatch.sendClickedQuery(selectedCat) {
        dispatch(mutations.sendQuery(propsFromState.lastQuery, selectedCat));
    }
    }
  );

export const ConnectedMain = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(Main);
```

And now you can call it like `props.sendQuery`. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Note that we recommend against using `mergeProps` in almost all situations.  It's an escape hatch, and not meant for common use.  Instead, we recommend using [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-the-object-shorthand-form-of-mapdispatch-with-connect), and then calling `this.props.doSomething(this.props.someValue)` inside the component.